# Parse.com php sdk: Show image stored in Parse

Tags: php, codeigniter, parse-platform, pffile

I am using Parse.com and php sdk integrated with codeigniter framework. I have ParseFile Info but how can i use it to show user's image without downloading it?

```
[userImage] => stdClass Object
    (
        [__type] => File
        [name] => tfss-1039551f-09e7-4a92-9ad4-4c08fa47c040-file
        [url] => http://files.parsetfss.com/4ffd6401-f550-4298-bea4-c7618ad44e57/tfss-1039551f-09e7-4a92-9ad4-4c08fa47c040-file
    )
```

Is there anyway I can use this to show user's image?
I am using this library https://github.com/st028/codeigniter-parse.com-library for my codeigniter framework

Answer (score 0):

You can use that url in img tag. #FACEPALM#